# How to assign websites for each internet connection. (Dealing with 2 internet connections)

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

Firstly I apology for my low networking skills.

So I have 2 internet connections from 2 ISPs. One is a 4G router via WiFi network and the other one is a 3G USB modem.

3G USB modem connection provides unlimited data **only** for **youtube**.

4G router is a limited internet connection and it has data caps.

My computer (it's windows 7 64-bit) is connected to both internet connections at the same time but **it doesn't use youtube via unlimited (3G USB modem) internet connection.**

I need to use youtube through 3G USB modem (since it's a youtube unlimited connection) and other websites through 4G router automatically.

I need your help with this.

Thanks!